# Beautiful soup doesn't get all elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the street addresses that are on the right side of the page (https://www.zillow.com/homes/San-Francisco,-CA_rb/) but insted off getting all I get only 9 of them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
}

response = requests.get(
    "https://www.zillow.com/homes/San-Francisco,-CA_rb/",
    headers=header)

data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

tag_adress = soup.find_all('address')

for x in tag_adress:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The site uses an api to access the data. I got the URL from dev tools. The script displays 500 addresses (500 agent lists, as the page states).

```
import requests
import json

useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5026.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/103.0.1254.0"

# obtained url from dev tools
url = "https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.63417331103516%2C%22east%22%3A-122.23248568896484%2C%22south%22%3A37.70660374673871%2C%22north%22%3A37.84391640339095%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A12%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22isAllHomes%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sortSelection%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22days%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D&wants={%22cat1%22:[%22mapResults%22]}&requestId=2"

page = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": useragent})
page.raise_for_status()

data = json.loads(page.content)

results = data["cat1"]["searchResults"]["mapResults"]

print(f"found {len(results)} results")

for item in results:
    address = item["address"]

    if address != "--":
        print(address)
```

Outputs:

```
found 500 results
1160 Mission St, San Francisco, CA
1000 N Point St, San Francisco, CA
750 Van Ness Ave, San Francisco, CA
3131 Pierce St, San Francisco, CA
2655 Bush St, San Francisco, CA
1288 Howard St, San Francisco, CA
765 Market St, San Francisco, CA
10 Innes Ct, San Francisco, CA
51 Innes Ct, San Francisco, CA
...
```